# Using Leaflet how can i loop through array for LonLat values?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to loop through an array to for the lon and lat but i get an errror

`Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lng')`

here is what is in the array:
`[427.913648, 1416.011817] [178.86422, 1180.050962] [200.868587, 969.076936] [197.867991, 709.098847] [188.866205, 679.10254] [167.862036, 680.102417] [193.867197, 647.106479] [125.853699, 652.105864] [100, 680]`

here is my code but I don't get any error in VSCode

```
    for (let c = 0; c < coordinates.length; c++) {
        console.log(coordinates[c])
        // console.log(c) coordinates[c]
        location[ln] = L.marker(coordinates[c], {icon:pcIcon}).addTo(map)
        location[ln].bindPopup(
            <div class="pinDrop">
                <h3>' + location[ln] + '</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img class="streetView" src="./assets/Images/Shipping.jpeg"/>
                <div>
                    <p>PC Name: ' + name[n] + '</p>
                    <p>Service Tag: ' + serviceTag[s] + '</p>
                    <p>IP Address: ' + workstationID[w] + '</p>
                    <p>IP Address: ' + ipAddress[i] + '</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

could anyone help me please?

if the lon and lat is typed in normally it works but it doesn't like looping through an array.

i am expecting to creating a marker at each lon and lat in the array.